# Variable declaration question mark

Tags: vb.net

I was looking at some existing code and stumbled across a variable declaration I didn't understand:

```
public foo as Boolean?
```

What does the question mark signify?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It means a [nullable `Boolean`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2cf62fcy.aspx).

`Boolean?`, or any other value type (number or struct), is shorthand for `Nullable(Of Boolean)`.

Comment: Here's the link for the vb.net examples since that's the tag in the original question: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235245.aspx

Answer (score 2):

aah, no sooner did I post the question that I realised that it may signify that it can be nullable.

I tested in code and that seems to be the case.

Comment: You should accept @SLaks's post as the answer to your question.