# How to cast from Object to Integer in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, string, casting, integer

How should I cast from an `Object` to an `Integer` in VB.NET?

When I do:

```
Dim intMyInteger as Integer = TryCast(MyObject, Integer)
```

it says:

> TryCast operand must be reference type, but Integer is a value type.

Comment: Why not this: CInt(MyObject)

Comment: @Dave - Read my comments on Abacus' answer. `Cint` (or any other *conversion* call) has a different purpose than `TryCast`/`DirectCast`. It is sensible if you have an incoming *numeric* value type, e.g. Single or Double, and want to truncate it to an Integer. Applying it to an incoming `Object` means you have no clue what is coming in, and what conversion work will be attempted. IMHO, it is a risky style of programming. Do what Jonathan shows, extending it if necessary. E.g., if you *want* to Parse a String, then check if its type is String, then call TryParse. Be explicit.

Comment: @Dave ... hopefully there will eventually be *Numeric* support in .Net. E.g. have all the numeric value types support an `INumeric` (or whatever) interface. Given that, instead of an incoming `MyObject As Object` one could have an incoming `MyNumber As INumeric`. OK, now we know "enough" about what is coming in, to do `CInt(MyNumber)`, and be confident that we know what work will be done.

Comment: Lest anyone think I am suggesting that conversion operators be avoided, I am specifically talking about applying them to `Object`. I consider that a "code smell". I am recommending not using conversion operators until you have identified some interface or base class - so that you have some clue what you are asking to be done, and what might go wrong. Know whether you are asking for string parsing, or numeric truncation, or merely "unboxing".

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`TryCast` is the equivalent of C#'s `as` operator. It is a "safe cast" operator that doesn't throw an exception if the cast fails. Instead, it returns `Nothing` (`null` in C#). The problem is, you can't assign `Nothing` (`null`) (a reference type) to an `Integer` (a value type).  There is no such thing as an `Integer` `null`/`Nothing`.

Instead, you can use `TypeOf` and `Is`:

```
If TypeOf MyObject Is Integer Then
    intMyInteger = DirectCast(MyObject, Integer)
Else
    intMyInteger = 0
End If
```

This tests to see if the *runtime type* of `MyObject` is `Integer`.  See the [MSDN documentation on the `TypeOf` operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ec5kw18.aspx) for more details.

You could also write it like this:

```
Dim myInt As Integer = If(TypeOf myObj Is Integer, DirectCast(myObj,Integer), 0)
```

Furthermore, if an integer with a default value (like 0) is not suitable, you could consider a `Nullable(Of Integer)` type.

Comment: Why would the type of `MyObject` be `Integer` when we already know it is `Object`?

Comment: We don't already know that. We only know that `MyObject` is an `Object` *reference*. It could still point to an object of any type. The [`If TypeOf x Is type` expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ec5kw18.aspx) tests the runtime type of the object.

Comment: Shouldn't this statement of yours be `iif` rather than `if`: `If(TypeOf myObj Is Integer, DirectCast(myObj,Integer), 0)` ?

Comment: Lowercase, they mean nothing. [`Iif`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/27ydhh0d.aspx) is a function, that has been replaced by the [`If`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513985.aspx) operator in VB 2008. A quick look at the MSDN docs goes a long way. (I'm answering your questions and don't even know Visual Basic.)

Comment: Assuming CJ7 knows what TryCast does, DirectCast does *not* do the same thing, the right equivalence is CType, see my answer below.

Comment: @Abacus Why the downvote? I'm still not seeing how my answer is incorrect, just because you've proposed an alternative.

Comment: Because the behavior of DirectCast is not the same as TryCast. If the input is an "Object" whose type is String and value is "1", DirectCast will throw an exception, where both TryCast and CType will do the cast.

Comment: Except going from a `String` "1" to an integer 1 is ***not*** a cast. It is a **conversion** (the string is **parsed**).  The OP is specifically asking about **casting** an `Object` reference that he's assuming is an integer to an integer value. I'd appreciate those rep points back, thank you.

Comment: NOTE: The usage of DirectCast here is correct - the test before DirectCast ensures that DirectCast is safe to do. An exception will NEVER be thrown by this code.

Comment: @CJ7 - using `IIf` here would **fail** (cause an exception if myObj is not an Integer). `IIf` always **evaluates** BOTH the true and false expressions; and then it returns whichever one is appropriate. The point of `If(..)` is that it only evaluates one expression or the other. In this case, it does not do `DirectCast` unless we have verified that we have an Integer. There is no situation in which using `IIf(..)` is a benefit; all uses of it in modern VB should be replaced by `If(..)`.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart - re "Lowercase, they mean nothing". FYI, VB is **not case sensitive**. So `iif` is exactly the same as `IIf`. It is up to the VB compiler to match the function name with the existing function signature, converting case as needed. But you are correct, there is no good use for `IIf(..)` any more, it is replaced by `If(..)` :)

Comment: @Abacus re *" If the input is an Object whose type is String and value is 1, DirectCast will throw an exception, where both TryCast and CType will do the cast."*  You misunderstand `TryCast`. You also confuse *casting* with *conversion*. `TryCast` will *not* do *conversion* - it will not attempt to parse a String to produce an Integer. And it is good that it does not; as a programmer, when you see TryCast, you know that a very limited and fast "upcasting" is being attempted.

Answer (score 5):

You can use this:

```
Dim intMyInteger as Integer

Integer.TryParse(MyObject, intMyInteger)
```

Comment: No, this is an answer to a **different** question than was asked by OP, which was **answered successfully two years ago**. First, observe that Integer.TryParse() does NOT accept an **Object** as its first parameter. It only works on **String**. This should be your first clue that OP's question about **casting** is not the same as **parsing**.

Comment: String inherits from Object, and this answer is valid. This is another answer to OP's question which was successfully answered 2 year ago. This option has a benefit, if the object contains an integer value in String format, the successful answer wouldn't work but this answer will. On the other hand, my answer will require boxing and unboxing, so that's the downside.

Answer (score 3):

Use Directcast and catch InvalidCastException

Comment: +1: At first glance, I thought this was not a good alternative, because exceptions are so expensive in .Net. However, OP did state he was expecting an Integer inside the Object; if it is indeed always (or almost always) an Integer, then it makes perfect sense to do the DirectCast, and only catch the (rare) exception. Though personally I use Jonathan's style, having been trained by years of .Net usage to avoid exceptions as "too expensive". Even in situations where they aren't.

Answer (score 2):

The equivalent for **TryCast** is **[CType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4x2877xb.aspx)**. Both will do a type conversion if it is possible. By contrast, **[DirectCast](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7k6y2h6x.aspx)** will only convert the type if it *is* that type already.

To illustrate, you can use **CType** to convert a String, or Short, or Double, to an Integer. **DirectCast** will generally give you a syntax/compile error if you do that; but if you try to go around the error by using type Object (this is called "boxing" and "unboxing"), it will throw an exception at run-time.

```
    Dim OnePointTwo As Object = "1.2"
    Try
        Dim temp = CType(OnePointTwo, Integer)
        Console.WriteLine("CType converted to: " & temp.ToString & " (type: " & temp.GetType.ToString & ")")
    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.WriteLine("CType threw exception")
    End Try
    Try
        Dim temp = DirectCast(OnePointTwo, Integer)
        Console.WriteLine("DirectCast converted to: " & temp.ToString & " (type: " & temp.GetType.ToString & ")")
    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.WriteLine("DirectCast threw exception")
    End Try
```

This will output:

```
    CType converted to: 1 (type: System.Int32)
    DirectCast threw exception
```

So to most closely follow the **TryCast** semantics, I suggest using a function like this:

```
Shared Function TryCastInteger(value As Object) As Integer?
    Try
        If IsNumeric(value) Then
            Return CType(value, Integer)
        Else
            Return Nothing
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return Nothing
    End Try
End Function
```

And to illustrate its effect:

```
Shared Sub TestTryCastInteger()
    Dim temp As Integer?

    Dim OnePointTwo As Object = "1.2"
    temp = TryCastInteger(OnePointTwo)
    If temp Is Nothing Then
        Console.WriteLine("Could not convert to Integer")
    Else
        Console.WriteLine("TryCastInteger converted to: " & temp.ToString & " (type: " & temp.GetType.ToString & ")")
    End If

    Dim NotANumber As Object = "bob's your uncle"
    temp = TryCastInteger(NotANumber)
    If temp Is Nothing Then
        Console.WriteLine("Could not convert to Integer")
    Else
        Console.WriteLine("TryCastInteger converted to: " & temp.ToString & " (type: " & temp.GetType.ToString & ")")
    End If
End Sub
```

Running TestTryCastInteger() will output:

```
    TryCastInteger converted to: 1 (type: System.Int32)
    Could not convert to Integer
```

There also *is* such a thing as a null/Nothing Integer, or any other static type, called a "nullable" type, see *[Variable declaration question mark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3208606/variable-declaration-question-mark)* for some more information. But that does not really make it a "reference" type either.

Comment: -1 for "the equivalent to TryCast is CType". Not really. The entire point of using TryCast is **to avoid the possibility of generating an exception at runtime**. CType **will** cause an exception, if the conversion fails. In addition, `TryCast` does not attempt the full range of conversions that `CType` attempts. The two are used quite differently. `TryCast` is a very **strict** (and fast) conversion: it attempts to "upcast" to a specific subclass. It is used when it was necessary to pass an instance as a more general base class. `CType` can do many more conversions -- which is good or bad ..

Comment: .. depending on the programmer's intent. It may attempt MUCH more expensive conversions, such as parsing a string. Its behavior can also be overloaded in custom classes, to do anything at all.  But even beyond that, the issue in recommending it here, is that you don't have enough information about what OP has in mind. It is a risky recommendation, that could lead to subtle bugs. It really shouldn't be used to cast from "Object", unless a programmer simply doesn't care what is coming in, and what the result will be -- they just "want it to work". The old, unreliable, way of Basic programming.

Comment: In summary, Jonathan is correct, if one's goal is to write a reliable program. If one has no control over the incoming type, and is stuck with an `Object` declaration, and you are expecting a `value` type, then the safe way to proceed is to start testing the object's type. Decide what to do, once you know what type of object you have.