# How to settle differences between TryParse Date and nullable date

Tags: .net, vb.net, date

When using tryparse to convert a date I get the following error:

> Error 1   Option Strict On disallows implicit conversions from 'Date?'
>   to
>   'Date'.

How can I still use a nullable date while making checks to ensure that the date is not only not null but also valid? This might not make sense at first glance but I need the ability to have a null date if it's not relevant but still need to check the date value for validation if it is used.

And yes, I'd definitely rather keep option strict on.

Comment: Makes the given type (Date) nullable (= accepting null/Nothing as input) and, consequently (slightly) different to the default one. Perhaps you should have googled it.

Comment: Did you not read my question?!?! I specifically state I couldn't Google it because Google doesn't accept special characters!

Comment: Honestly, I did stop reading your question after the first two lines :) (I rarely do that, but in this case it seemed acceptable). In any case, what about: "question mark type vb.net"?

Comment: Understandable, at least you didn't downvote.

Comment: I rarely downvote. Although I vote to close and this seems repeated (try the aforementioned string in google.com).

Comment: possible duplicate of [variable declaration question mark](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3208606/variable-declaration-question-mark)

Comment: @varocarbas I suppose this question is asking what I can do about it. Your suggestion is just clarifying what it is.

Comment: As @varocarbas points out, the `Date?` is the same as `Nullable(Of Date)`, so you could try using Nullable in your Google search. If you want help with the underlying problem, please edit your question to show the statement that fails as well as how the variables in that statement are declared.

Comment: Why are you using Date? since you don't know what it is?

Comment: I now understand the meaning of Date? so have edited the question to focus on my specific issue of how to use Date and null-able dates in a .tryparse.

Comment: @dbasnett I didn't understand the direct relation between nullable(Of Date) declaration and Date? data type.

Comment: I have voted to close this because it is impossible to answer when you keep editing the question to add more conditions and there is no code posted in it either

Comment: _How to settle differences_? Put them together in the ring and let them fight it out :)

Comment: @MattWilko I edited the question in order first to prove that it wasn't a duplicate and then to clarify the question. I'd admit my question wasn't clear after the first edit so I edited after for further clarification. I've also already accepted an answer, to close now would be a waste!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use Date.TryParse with a Nullable(Of Date) the Nullable(Of Date) must have a value to begin with.

```
    Dim dt As Date? = Date.MinValue

    If Date.TryParse("9/1/2015", dt.Value) Then
    Else
        dt = New Nullable(Of Date)
    End If
```

Alternatively you can use a Date in the TryParse and if successful assign it to the Nullable.

```
    Dim dt As Date? 
    Dim dtemp As Date
    If Date.TryParse("9/1/2015", dtemp) Then
        dt = dtemp
    Else
    End If
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated before, ? states is Nullable. You can use methods like HasValue() or GetValueOrDefault() on it. See this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx).

You edited your question. Try this;

```
If nullableDate.HasValue  Then
  date = nullableDate.Value
End If
```

Comment: Just as some constructive criticism, my tag is vb.net not (what I assume) C. Still stored my issue however :)

Comment: Hmm posting C# on a question tagged VB.NET is not good in my book. Imagine if this was the other way around? Also the C# posted does not compile.

Comment: Edited the question to ask how I can check for null AND validate the date. Such this answer no longer fully covers the question.

Comment: True, had a few tabs open and the question got edited a few times. Lost track of the language and it was meant like pseudo code so someone will have to do it himself and learn;)

Comment: Now you say; AND validate the date. Validate against what? A value? Use AndAlso date.Value == xxxx

Comment: @Erik Validate as a valid date rather than just a random string. That was always my intention and I apologise for not making it clearer earlier.